# Replace x by float(x) if and only if it is not None

Tags: python, nonetype

`x` is either a string or `None` (for example a query param from a HTTP request: `request.query.get('x')`).

I'd like to transform it into a `float` if not `None`.

These 3 solutions work:

```
if x is None:
    y = None
else:
    y = float(x)

y = float(x) if x is not None else None    # or y = float(x) if x is not None else x

y = None if x is None else float(x)        # or y = x if x is None else float(x)
```

but probably is there a simpler way than this repetition of `None`?

Comment: What should actually happen if `x` is an empty string?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel in the geneal context of my question it should fail with an exception, but in the specific case of `request.query.get('x')`, I realize a better solution is just `y = float(x) if x else None` because `if x` avoids the 2 cases: empty string `""` and `None`.

Comment: But that also doesn't catch the exception if `x` is not a valid floating point number

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yes in the case of a HTTP request query param, of course we can add many other validation checks, but this would be out of topic; here for the question it's just about comparison with None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
>>> x = "1.23"
>>> y = x and float(x)
>>> y
1.23
>>> x = None
>>> y = x and float(x)
>>> y
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using exception handling. This handles empty string (`ValueError`) and when `x == None` (`TypeError`).

```py
try:
    y = float(x)
except Exception:
    y = None
```